# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no se repita un mismo elemento?

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade

```html
<ul>
  @foreach ($proveedores as $ac)
    <li>{{ucfirst($ac['nomProveedorSucursal'])}}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Ese foreach recorre todos los elementos, hay algunos que se repiten lo que quiero es que solo se impriman uno por cada elemento diferente que haya dentro del arreglo ejemplo;

- incorrecto

  - elemento 1
  - elemento 2
  - elemento 2
- correcto

  - elemento 1
  - elemento 2

Comment: que valor tiene $proveedores? es una colección o un array?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ una colección

Comment: ok, escribí una respuesta de cómo prodrías filtrar la colección usando el método unique()

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya lo implemente y me funciono perfecto gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal sería ya traer los datos como los necesitas desde la consulta a BD, pero si por alguna razón necesitas que la consulta traiga todos los datos y solamente filtrar los que no sean repetidos para este foreach, puedes usar el método [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-unique), especificando la clave utilizada para determinar la unicidad:

```
<ul>
  @foreach ($proveedores->unique('nomProveedorSucursal') as $ac)
    <li>{{ucfirst($ac['nomProveedorSucursal'])}}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a utilizar `SELECT DISTINCT` en la consulta que hagas a tu base de datos?.
Suponiendo un campo nombre_proveedor que tengas en tu tabla:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `nombre_proveedor` FROM `nombre_tu_tabla`
```

Si utilizas Laravel sería así:

```
Proveedores::distinct()->get(['nombre_proveedor']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un HashMap para emular el comportamiento de un Set. No es lo mas "bonito" ni eficiente del mundo, pero como primera aproximación puede servir.

```
<?php
   //$proovedores = [...];
   $array = array();
   foreach ($proovedores as $a){
       $array[$a['nomProveedorSucursal']]=$a;
   }
?>
```

Ahora puedes iterar sobre *$array*, que tendra valores unicos

```
<ul>
  @foreach ($array as $ac)
    <li>{{ucfirst($ac['nomProveedorSucursal'])}}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```